# How to make jQuery or WordPress PHP that counts characters then finds last space and replace all content after with "..."

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, charactercount

I need to limit the amount of text displayed within a div from a WordPress Custom Field.

```
<?php $textcount = strlen(get_field('custom_quote')); ?>
<?php if ( $textcount > 250 ) : ?>
    <?php the_field('custom_quote'); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php the_field('custom_quote'); ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Want this: (351 Characters With Spaces) →

> Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast
> yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin
> grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey
> doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters. Deadlights jack
> lad schooner scallywag dance the hempen jig carouser broadside cable
> strike colors.

To find the space right before 250 Characters and then add the string value "..." in place of the " ". like this →

> Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast
> yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin
> grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey
> doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway...

I'm not trying to limit the character count of the Custom Field because I need it to render the max text on a desktop display and then limit the text on a `@media(max-width: 768px){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You this [wp_trim_words()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/). check below code.

```
<?php $textcount = strlen(get_field('custom_quote')); ?>
<?php if ( $textcount > 250 ) : ?>
    <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_field('custom_quote'), 33, '...' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php the_field('custom_quote') ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: get_the_field() → get_field()